# woocommerce_cart_updated hook is not working as expected - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I have a plugin that uses `woocommerce_cart_updated` hook to do something when the cart contents change.

*`woocommerce_cart_updated` seems to be fired on every page load.*

> Is there any way to restrict this hook in some pages like
> *my-account*.?

> **Is there any single hook that I can call on any cart updated ( add , remove / update quantity/restore).?**

By using different hooks - there is some workaround for this.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', $cart_item_key, $this );
do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_restored', $cart_item_key, $this );
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', $cart_item_key, $quantity, $old_quantity );
```

> Is there any option to get the pagename or slug in the callback
> function of this hook. ( `woocommerce_cart_updated` ). So I can restrict this action in some pages.?

But as far as I can tell — it's being run even when the session variables haven't been updated. **It's being fired all the time, no matter what.**

Comment: Your question seems too vague… If I had a real related working answer, it will be already there since a while.

Comment: See this discussion: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/13542
Describes your issue and possible work arounds similar to what you're suggesting.